# Managing open and closed menus on custom accordion navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a basic accordion style menu: http://jsfiddle.net/JqJce/1/

```
<ul class="nav level-1">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="level-3">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul></li>
</ul>
```

```
a {
    display:block;
    background:#aaa;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
}
li li {
    display:none;
}

/* Open/Closed indicators */
.has-submenu > a:after {
 content:' + ';
}
.has-submenu .nav-open:after {
 content:' - ';
}

li li a {
   padding-left:40px;
    background:#888;
}
li li li a {
   padding-left:80px;
    background:#333;
}
```

Here's what I want to happen:

- When a link that has a submenu is clicked, its submenu slides down
- When an open submenu's link is clicked again, the menu collapses
- Only one top-level submenu should be shown at a time (showing multiple "level 2" or "level 3" menus at once is OK)
- Unopened menus should display `+`, open menus should display `-`
- I cannot change the HTML markup unfortunately

Here's what I've got:

```
$('.has-submenu > a').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    // Need to add/remove .nav-open from links
    // $('a').removeClass('nav-open');
    $(this).toggleClass('nav-open');

    // Not sure what I'm thinking here...   
    // $('.level-1 > .has-submenu').not($(this).parent()).find('li').slideUp();

    // Sort of works, but clicking an open menu makes it close and open again
    // $('.level-2 > li').not($(this).parent()).slideUp();

    $(this).next('ul').find('> li').slideToggle();

});
```

The code above works perfectly for opening and closing menus, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly close the other `level-1` menus when a new one is opened and change the icon. I've been struggling with this for a while and have a feeling I'm missing something rather simple. I think my brain is just fried right now.

Can anyone help? Please let me know if I can clarify anything. http://jsfiddle.net/JqJce/1/

Comment: Do you mean that when a submenu is open and you click another submenu, that the first should collapse? If so, you should loop all the menus, check if its open, if yes, close it.

Comment: When a submenu is open and you click another *top-level* submenu, the others should collapse. Once that menu is open, submenus within it should not toggle anything except itself when clicked. I'm not sure what you mean by "loop all the menus", it seems there must be a selector I can use for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a way:

```
$('.has-submenu > a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // slide up currently open except if click 
    // occurs within an already open menu
    if ($(this).closest('.nav-open').length === 0)
    {
        $('.nav > .nav-open').removeClass('nav-open').find('> ul > li').slideUp();
    }

    // give the <li> the "nav-open" class, then slide the <li> grandchildren
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('nav-open').find('> ul > li').slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JqJce/6/

I'm setting the `nav-open` class on the `<li>` parent of the `<a>` vs on the `<a>` itself

Also updated this CSS:

```
.nav-open > a:after {
    content:' - ';
}
```

Comment: You certainly understood my requirements so +1 for that alone, just give me a little while to wedge this into the production code and see if there's any issue.

Comment: By the way here is a version with the `+/-` working: http://jsfiddle.net/JqJce/9/

Comment: but I think this will not work for the inner submenus, the same problem persists as the op required for the inner menus

Comment: This is working perfectly, and moving the nav-open class was no issue. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: nav-open is not part of html then based on that how we can check and removeClass.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it for you through a bunch of trial and error.

http://jsfiddle.net/JqJce/7/

```
$('.has-submenu > a').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).next('ul').find('> li').slideToggle();

    // If it's a level one link & there's other open links...
    if($(this).parent("li").parent("ul").hasClass("level-1") && $(".level-1 > li > a").hasClass("nav-open")) {
        //... collapse the top level open link.
        $(".level-1 > li > a.nav-open").next('ul').find('> ').slideToggle();
        $(".level-1 > li > a.nav-open").removeClass("nav-open");
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('nav-open');
});
```

I have to believe there's a more efficient way to handle this, but like you, my brain is now fried! Good luck!

Comment: I was too busy pounding away to see @MikeM's answer. You can probably safely ignore mine.

Comment: Thanks but this is rather buggy (for example click a link, then click it again). I do appreciate it though.