# Only one submenu should be open at a time

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s125paua/

Following is html of list

```
<div id="div1">

<ul class="nav level-1">

<li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Menu Level1</a>
    <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Menu-Level2</a>
        <ul class="level-3">
                        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Menu Level3</a>
            <ul class="level-4">
                        <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
                        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Menu-Level3</a>
            <ul class="level-3">
                        <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                    </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Menu-Level2</a>
            <ul class="level-3">
                <li><a href="#">Menu-Level3</a></li>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Menu-Level3</a>

                    <ul class="level-4">
                        <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu-Level4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Menu-Level1</a>
    <ul class="level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Menu-Level2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu-Level2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

 </ul>
</div>
```

I have referred following [Managing open and closed menus on custom accordion navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363790/managing-open-and-closed-menus-on-custom-accordion-navigation/18364288#18364288)

Here nav-open class is used but it is not at all part of html.

I need to do following things:

When a link that has a submenu is clicked, its submenu expands
When an open submenu's link is clicked again, the menu collapses
Only "level 2" or "level 3" or "level 4" menus should be open at once.

Comment: Your question confusing me a little, if I understand correctly... have you tried the siblings() function ? It returns all siblings, you can then go and use find() and/or each() to resolve your issue

Comment: @Lost here is fiddle for the question http://jsfiddle.net/s125paua/. I have nested menu of 4 levels. so i am confused how to open only one menu  at at time

Answer (score 2):

I am having trouble in understanding your html , however i have created a sample for you here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h34LL8pu/)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menumain">
   <li class="MenuLevelOne MenuDD"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">History</a>
  <ul class="MenuLevelTwo">
     <li><a href="#">Brief History</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Brandon at War</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Heritage Centre</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Historic Maps</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
     <li class="MenuLevelOne MenuDD"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Community</a>
     <ul class="MenuLevelTwo">
     <li><a href="#">Brief History</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Brandon at War</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Heritage Centre</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Historic Maps</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(".MenuDD").click(function () {
$(this).siblings().find("ul").hide();
$(this).find("ul").toggle();
$(this).siblings().removeClass('darkbg');
$(this).toggleClass("darkbg");
});
```

Comment: For him/her to easier use & understand your fiddle, perhaps remove href or add onclick to your "levelTwo" menu anchor tags. But yes this should give a great base to build on.

Answer (score 1):

Ok if I understand now.. you are trying to close all siblings and then only open the clicked sub menu, change your js to this:

```
            $('.has-submenu > a').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).parent().toggleClass('nav-open').find('> ul > li').slideToggle();

            $(this).parent().siblings().find('> ul > li').slideUp();


        });
```

EDIT: Add this after last line to fix toggle class

```
$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('nav-open');
```